# Dealing with ranges of numbers

Tags: c#, oop

I need to return a value that corresponds to some weighting for a calculation based on age.

Here's the age ranges and weights:-

```
21-30: 1.2
31-40: 1.8
41-50: 1.9
```

and so on (there's no real pattern)

The program needs to take an age as input and then return the weighting (e.g. if age = 35, the return value would be 1.8.

How would this be best achieved?

I could use `switch` but I'm not sure if it's the best way around this. Is there some other construct or technique I could apply in C# to achieve this that would be more effective and portable/scalable should the weightings change?

One other thing - I can't use a database to store any weightings data - just adding this for info.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Dictionary to define your age ranges and weights. The key should be a Tuple with the min-age and max-age for this range and the value should be your weight:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>, double>  // minAge, MaxAge -> weight
```

Then you may loop through all keys to find your weight.

You may create this dictionary from the contents of a table, a XML file, a database, whatever.

Comment: A dictionary doesn't really help here since you don't have the `Tuple` to do a lookup with.  Might as well be a `List<Tuple<int,int,double>>`.

Comment: @juharr Well, I just use the fact that it is a key/value collection with the possibilty to enumerate the keys. Makes it slightly _simpler_ to use than a list.

Answer (score 1):

We have done something similar in a system here, and we use the concept of storing in a database table the weighting and the lower threshold.  Thus all we need to do is to find the record with the highest lower threshold less than the value entered and read the weight.

This simplifies the process and allows for editing and adding and removing the values.

Comment: Forgot to add - I can't use a database table to achieve this.  Sorry - forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

If the ranges are consecutive as they appear to be in your example, you only need the upper value and the ranges sorted in order to be able to query it, so you can do something like this:

```
public class RangeEntry
{
    public RangeEntry(int upperValue, float weight)
    {
        UpperValue = uperValue;
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public int UpperValue { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}

public class RangeWeights
{
    private List<RangeEntry> _ranges = new List<RangeEntry>
    {
        new RangeEntry(30, 1.2f),
        new RangeEntry(40, 1.8f),
        new RangeEntry(50, 1.9f),
    }

    public float GetWeight(int value)
    {
        // If you pre-sort the ranges then you won't need the below OrderBy
        foreach (var r in _ranges.OrderBy(o => o.UpperValue)) 
        {
            if (value <= r.UpperValue)
                return r.Weight;
        }

        // Range not found, do whatever you want here
        throw new InvalidOperationException("value not within in any valid range");
    }
}
```

The value of this approach is that adding a new range means adding just 1 line of code in the instantiation of the ranges.

Comment: In your `RangeEntry` constructor the `weight` parameter should be a `float` and not a `int`.

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I know, there is nothing like a range-structure.

You could use a switch, either in this way, if the ranges are always from x1 to y0

```
switch((value-1) / 10)
{
    case 1: ... break; 
    case 2: ... break;
}
```

or, if needed:

```
switch(value)
{
    case 11:
    case 12:
    case 20: ... break;
    case 21: ... 
}
```

Depending on the number of groups you need, you could do checks like

```
if(value > 10 && <= 20) ...
```

I don't know any more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what is the structure of the age ranges and weights data,
but I would probably do something like this:

```
Class AgeRangeAndWeight {
   int FromAge {get;set;}
   int ToAge {get;set;}
   double Weight {get;set;}
}

Class AgeRangeAndWeight Collection() : List<AgeRangeAndWeight> {
  AgeRangeAndWeight FindByAge(int age) {
    foreach(AgeRangeAndWeight araw in this) {
      if(age >= araw.FromAge && age <= araw.ToAge) {
        return araw;
      }
    }
  return null;
  }
}
```

then all you have to do is call the FindByAge method. remember to check that it doesn't return null.

**Update**
Five years after I've posted this answer it was upvoted.
Today I wouldn't recommend inheriting a `List<T>` - but simply use it's `Find` method like this:

```
var list = new List<AgeRangeAndWeight>() {/* populate here */}
var age = 35;
var ageRangeAndWeight = list.Find(a => d.FromAge >= age && d.ToAge <= age);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ranges do not overlap then the best thing to use would be a [`SortedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where the key is the upper value of the range, and the value is the weight.  Additionally you can make the weigth nullable to distinguish the case of not finding an entry.  I've added the entry of `{20, null}` so that if the age is <= 20 you'll get `null` instead of 1.2.

```
var rangedWeights = new SortedList<int, float?>
{
     { 20, null }
     { 30, 1.2f }, 
     { 40, 1.8f }, 
     { 50, 1.9f }
};

int age = 44;
float? weight = null;
foreach (var kvp in rangedWeights)
{
    if (age <= kvp.Key)
    {
        weight = kvp.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can dynamically add new entries and still be sure they are sorted.

```
rangedWeights.Add(60, 2.1f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary with composite key, which you will use to check the  user input and get the respected value for the matching key.

Here is example;

```
        Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double> t = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, double>();

        t.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(11,20),1f);
        t.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(21, 30), 2f);
        t.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(31, 40), 3f);

        int weight = 34;

        double rr = (from d in t where d.Key.Item1 <= weight && d.Key.Item2 >= weight select d.Value).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(rr);  // rr will print 3.0
```

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a shorter way of writing it, I suggest you use [?: operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

```
double getWeight(int age){
    return (age <= 30) ? 1.2 :
           (age <= 40) ? 1.8 : 1.9;
}
```

It will be the same as using switch. Only shorter way of putting it. You can replace the digits and weights with variables if you don't want them to be hard coded.